# Get array values when key is string

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

There's no doubt this hasn't already be en asked before, but I can't for the life of me find the answer.

I have a seemingly simple array:

```
Array
(
    [title] => Array
        (
            [0] => Price
            [1] => BBB Rating
        )
    [description] => Array
        (
            [0] => How much you pay
            [1] => Their standing with the BBB
        )
)
```

I'm trying to `foreach` loop the Title+Description of each key but for some reason nothing I'm doing is working.

Expected output is:

```
<ul>
  <li>Price: How much you pay</li>
  <li>BBB Rating: Their standing with the BBB</li>
</ul>
```

I've tried:

```
<?php foreach ($options[$overview] as $item => $value) : ?>
  <li><?php echo $item[title][0] . ': ' . $item[description][0]; ?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

and every variation of swapping $value, $item, [0], etc.

Comment: DID you try anything?? Show us what you try?

Answer (score -1):

You can use just a regular old `for` loop pretty straightforward. You need to loop the length of one of the inner arrays title/description (assuming they are the same) then echo the content of the index that the loop is on.

Also, I prefer String Interpolation over concatenation in instance like this.

```
$main = array(); // your array with price/ description
echo "<ul>";
for($i=0; $i <= count($main['title']); $i++){
    echo "<li>";
    echo "{$main['title'][$i]}: {$main['description'][$i]}";
    echo "</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: Ah yes the mysterious downvote to an answer cause someone does not like the question. So forget my good mood this morning.

Answer (score -1):

```
$entities = Array
(
[title] => Array
    (
        [0] => Price
        [1] => BBB Rating
    )
[description] => Array
    (
        [0] => How much you pay
        [1] => Their standing with the BBB
    )
)
```

So it can be achieved like this.

```
<ul>
foreach($entities as $entity){
    foreach($entity['title'] as $key => $title):
        <li><?php echo $title[$key]; ?>: <?php echo $entity['description'][$key]; ?></li>
    <?php endforeach ?>
}
</ul>
```

Comment: If you've down voted something please explain the reasons.